# Setting up gamecenter to allow connections over cellular network

Tags: iphone, game-center

How does one setup game-center to be able to connect to users where ever. With both users being on a cellular 3G/4G network or on wifi?

I have setup a p2p app using game-center and only players on the same wifi network can connect to one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Game Center provides all the infrastructure to play all around the world via their servers (in 3G or Wifi). With the Game Center you can play up to 4 players (multi-player games), it's free, you don't have to manage any server, there is a mechanism of invitation between friends, and many more.

You can find all information on the official documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH5-SW7). If you want, there is a very tuto on the [ray wenderlich's blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12) (but it uses the cocos2d framework instead of the CocoaTouch).